# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo android.view.InflateException

Tags: android, exception, view, android-inflate

I am developing an application that consists of analog gauge and i found library from analog gauge from [here](https://github.com/CodeAndMagic/GaugeView). when i was adding the library to the downloaded project it was added successfully and works fine. But When it comes to my project, When i added same gauge view Library to my project by project properties->android->add->choose library->ok. when i click Ok it was showing an red color cross mark beside library and i was tried to add jar file of the library also but it would not succeeded for me showing  **java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.lakshman.samplelibraryproj/com.lakshman.samplelibraryproj.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class org.codeandmagic.android.gauge.GaugeView**. Please Help me with this i was trying this since from 4 hours

this is my Xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

       <org.codeandmagic.android.gauge.GaugeView
        android:id="@+id/gauge_view1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

this is my logcat:

```
01-02 00:24:36.600: E/AndroidRuntime(4126): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-02 00:24:36.600: E/AndroidRuntime(4126): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.lakshman.samplelibraryproj/com.lakshman.samplelibraryproj.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class org.codeandmagic.android.gauge.GaugeView
01-02 00:24:36.600: E/AndroidRuntime(4126):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
01-02 00:24:36.600: E/AndroidRuntime(4126):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
01-02 00:24:36.600: E/AndroidRuntime(4126):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-02 00:24:36.600: E/AndroidRuntime(4126):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
01-02 00:24:36.600: E/AndroidRuntime(4126):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-02 00:24:36.600: E/AndroidRuntime(4126):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-02 00:24:36.600: E/AndroidRuntime(4126):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
01-02 00:24:36.600: E/AndroidRuntime(4126):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-02 00:24:36.600: E/AndroidRuntime(4126):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-02 00:24:36.600: E/AndroidRuntime(4126):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
01-02 00:24:36.600: E/AndroidRuntime(4126):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-02 00:24:36.600: E/AndroidRuntime(4126):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-02 00:24:36.600: E/AndroidRuntime(4126): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class org.codeandmagic.android.gauge.GaugeView
01-02 00:24:36.600: E/AndroidRuntime(4126):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
01-02 00:24:36.600: E/AndroidRuntime(4126):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
01-02 00:24:36.600: E/AndroidRuntime(4126):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
01-02 00:24:36.600: E/AndroidRuntime(4126):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
01-02 00:24:36.600: E/AndroidRuntime(4126):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
01-02 00:24:36.600: E/AndroidRuntime(4126):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
01-02 00:24:36.600: E/AndroidRuntime(4126):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
01-02 00:24:36.600: E/AndroidRuntime(4126):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
01-02 00:24:36.600: E/AndroidRuntime(4126):     at com.lakshman.samplelibraryproj.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
01-02 00:24:36.600: E/AndroidRuntime(4126):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
01-02 00:24:36.600: E/AndroidRuntime(4126):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
01-02 00:24:36.600: E/AndroidRuntime(4126):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
01-02 00:24:36.600: E/AndroidRuntime(4126):     ... 11 more
01-02 00:24:36.600: E/AndroidRuntime(4126): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01-02 00:24:36.600: E/AndroidRuntime(4126):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
01-02 00:24:36.600: E/AndroidRuntime(4126):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
01-02 00:24:36.600: E/AndroidRuntime(4126):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
01-02 00:24:36.600: E/AndroidRuntime(4126):     ... 22 more
01-02 00:24:36.600: E/AndroidRuntime(4126): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.codeandmagic.android.gauge.R$styleable
01-02 00:24:36.600: E/AndroidRuntime(4126):     at org.codeandmagic.android.gauge.GaugeView.readAttrs(GaugeView.java:183)
01-02 00:24:36.600: E/AndroidRuntime(4126):     at org.codeandmagic.android.gauge.GaugeView.<init>(GaugeView.java:170)
01-02 00:24:36.600: E/AndroidRuntime(4126):     at org.codeandmagic.android.gauge.GaugeView.<init>(GaugeView.java:175)
01-02 00:24:36.600: E/AndroidRuntime(4126):     ... 25 more
```

Comment: Check your `org.codeandmagic.android.gauge.GaugeView` Package name carefully...

Comment: i checked it and replaced with the library name then again it'll occurs like The following classes could not be instantiated:
- org.codeandmagic.android.gauge.GaugeView (Open Class, Show Error Log)
See the Error Log (Window > Show View) for more details.

Comment: Select your GaugeView Library and clean it by "project --> clean", then build it again.

Comment: I did it but remains same @Leog

Comment: You should not add jar file of the library to your project directly but add it with your first method( properties->android->add). If the error still exist after rebuild your project and library, please post the Errors that you can find at Window-->Show View-->Problems.

Comment: It was showing an error in xml called ::-->The following classes could not be found:
- org.codeandmagic.android.gauge (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)